# Convert csv cells to a nested list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, csv

I have a .csv file with a column which contains a list of values structured as well:

[image]

What I wanna do is create a nested list with all the values in the following format, so I can iterate through them with another method:

```
[[1009, 1310], [9420, 9699], [11590, 12009], [12290, 12499], [14460, 14809]]
```

I tried to read it by simple converting the cell to a list:

```
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', usecols=['anomaly_sequences'])
a = df.iloc[0]['anomaly_sequences']
print(a[0])
```

But the output I got is: `[`

If I check its type with `print(a.dtype)` I get:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

How can I read it directly as a list instead of a string?

Comment: HI Fabio, please provide a [mcve]. In particular try to share text/code instead of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `literal_eval` from the standard ast library to take a string and evaluate it as python code.

```
import ast
df['anomaly_sequences'] = df['anomaly_sequences'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Comment: I think OP has the data of the form `df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':'[(1,2),(3,4)]'})` and what he wants is to have `list of lists` instead of `list of tuples`

Comment: He expressed the need to iterate over them and index them - that can be achieved with either kind of list.

Comment: This solution gives me `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index` for the df I posted in above comment

Comment: Updated to use literal_eval instead of safe_eval. This converts strings to python literals, so your sequence field should convert.